# Connect TFS in visual studio 2017 macbook

Tags: macos, visual-studio, tfs

I got stuck in connecting TFS in visual studio 2017 mac. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: What error did you get? How did you connect TFS? Can you share your detailed steps or screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

First, check the requirements of connecting to Team Foundation version control from VS for Mac, to see whether your environment meets the requirements:

> - Visual Studio Community, Professional, or Enterprise for Mac version
>     7.5 or later.
> - Visual Studio Team Services, or Team Foundation Server 2013 and    later.
> - A Project in Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server,    configured to use Team Foundation Version Control.

Then follow the steps below to install the extension and connect to VSTS/TFS:

1. In Visual Studio for Mac, choose **Visual Studio** > **Extensions**... from the menu. In the **Gallery** tab, select **Version Control** > **Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and VSTS** and click **Install**…:

[image]

2. Updates to the TFVC extension are made periodically. To access updates, choose **Visual Studio** > **Extensions**... from the menu and select the **Updates** tab. Select the extension in the list and press the *Update* button:

[image]

3. Once the extension is installed, select the **Version Control** > **TFS/VSTS** > **Open from Remote Repository** menu item.

Choose either Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server to get started and press **Continue**:

[image]

4. Enter the TFS server information or VSTS credential, and select a project.

More details you can refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control

Comment: I am getting server authentication failed when I am trying in this way. But I am able to access the repository through browser.

Comment: But when I am trying through terminal I am getting no workspace matching * (star)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of how did you add your credential?

Comment: Its not a solution, it's the same as in the documentation. I have the same issue like this post: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/253900/visual-studio-for-mac-tfs-extension-will-not-insta.html

Comment: I found an alternative solution by using a stable version of the tfs which is found in: https://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/315

Answer (score 0):

If using TFS 2017, it has the option of using git for repositories and Visual Studio 2017 for Mac as of v7.8.3 (build2) doesn't support git in TFS yet.